# Custom cursor not supported in Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, mouse-cursor

```js
if(!CSS.supports('cursor', 'url(cursor.png), pointer')) {
    var myCursor = document.createElement('img');

    myCursor.src = 'cursor.png';
    myCursor.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(myCursor);

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        myCursor.style.left = e.pageX+'px';
        myCursor.style.top = e.pageY+'px';
    }, false);
}
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #19321D;
    color: #53CC66;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
    cursor: url(cursor.png), pointer;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #53CC66;
}

ul{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #53CC66;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    line-height: 1;
}

h1, h2, h3{
    color: #53CC66;
    font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
}

a{
  cursor: url(cursor.png), pointer;  
}

a:hover {
  cursor: url(cursor.png), pointer;  
  color: #19321D;
}

li:hover{
background-color:#53CC66;  
color: #19321D;
}

li:hover a{  
color: #19321D;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Getrate|Command promph </title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles15.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        
            <h1>DAVID SECRET INDUSTRIES UNVERIFIED SYSTEM</h1>
            <h2>COPYRIGHT 2015 - 2050 ALL RIGHT RESERVED</h2>
            <h3>- SERVER #1 -</h3>
        
    </div>
    
    <ul>
    <li><a href="birthday.php">[CONZOLE]  >  -TOP SECRET- . PAGE //stripslash 1.3.8.9.84.113.21.73</a></li>
    <li><a href="birthday.php">[CONZOLE]  >  -TOP SECRET- . PAGE //stripslash 1.4.8.9.84.113.21.74</a></li>
    <li><a href="documents_gate.php">[CONZOLE]  >  -TOP SECRET- . PAGE //stripslash 1.5.8.9.84.113.21.75</a></li>
    <li><a href="birthday.php">[CONZOLE]  >  -TOP SECRET- . PAGE //stripslash 1.6.8.9.84.113.21.76</a></li>
    <li><a href="birthday.php">[CONZOLE]  >  -TOP SECRET- . PAGE //stripslash 1.7.8.9.84.113.21.77</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>    
    
</body>
    <script src="wow.js"></script>
</html>
```

I just thought, is there any possible way, to make custom cursor, that works on microsoft edge? On [my website](http://david.addagio.cz/promph), i used this:

```
body{ cursor: url(cursor.png), pointer;}
```

but in microsoft edge, it is not working...

Any ideas how to solve this?/Is there any other way?

---

So.... after small recode, my website looks like this, see the fiddle and try, it is not working yet...

Answer (score 4):

<del>This property is not supported yet : http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor</del>

This property is now supported : [**caniuse.com:`cursor:url()`**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_cursor_url)

Comment: Well, that is Maybe true, but i need the solution :)

Comment: The snippet by @benjamin-solum works : https://jsfiddle.net/9hj2wd87/
If you are unable to implement it, the way you are asking (as if we were bounty hinters) doesn't really encourage people to do more. This isn't enough challenging.

Comment: Looks like it is NOT transforming the mouse, into image, but ONLY make like another layer, for the image, not working

Answer (score 3):

As Charaf mentioned: [the property isn't yet supported in Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor). If your project requires a solution, you can sort of mimic the behavior with JavaScript.

**JavaScript:**

```
if(!CSS.supports('cursor', 'url(cursor.png), pointer')) {
    var myCursor = document.createElement('img');

    myCursor.src = 'cursor.png';
    myCursor.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(myCursor);

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        myCursor.style.left = e.pageX+'px';
        myCursor.style.top = e.pageY+'px';
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: I will check, if it works soon, than i will give you 50 rep. points :) thanks for the best answer

Comment: Ok, not working, but this may be caused by my low skills in javascript, please see the code snippet and try to figure out, how to repair it :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a library called **CursorJS** for you. You can [check it out here](https://jsfiddle.net/gfLsgjp4/3/). If you scroll to the bottom of the JavaScript code, you can find initializing code:

```
/* Enable lib with cursor image src */
CursorJS.enable('http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/plastic-mini-icons-by-deleket/png/32x32/Cursor-01.png');
CursorJS.addEl(document.querySelector('.myElement1'));
CursorJS.addEl(document.querySelector('.myElement3'));
```

In your case just do the following:

```
/* Enable lib with cursor image src */
CursorJS.enable('./cursor.png');
CursorJS.addEl(document.body);
```

---

## Customization

CursorJS has a `mouseOffset` variable. It repesents difference of mouse position and position of image. For example, if I set it to

```
mouseOffset: {
    x: 50,
    y: 50
},
```

The mouse will be 50px off. The reason why I made this variable is that custom mouse was kind of "blinking", try to set it to *{x:1,y:1}* ;)

---

## Live example

```js
var CursorJS = {
 img: new Image(),
 els: [],
 mouseOffset: {
  x: 5,
  y: 5
 },
 addedImg: false,
 checkForIE: function() {
  return (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
    || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
 },
 setDisplay: function() {
  this.img.style.display =
   this.els.indexOf(true) > -1 ? null : 'none';
 },
 getMouseCoords: function(e) {
  var mx = 0, my = 0;
  if (this.checkForIE())
   mx = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
   my = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  else
   mx = e.pageX,my = e.pageY;
  if (mx < 0) mx = 0;
  if (my < 0) my = 0;
  return [mx, my];
 },
 mouseOver: function(e, id) {
  this.els[id] = true;
  this.setDisplay();
  var coords = this.getMouseCoords(e);
  this.img.style.left = 
   (coords[0]+this.mouseOffset.x) + 'px';
  this.img.style.top = 
   (coords[1]+this.mouseOffset.y) + 'px';
 },
 mouseOut: function(e, id) {
  this.els[id] = false;
  this.setDisplay();
 },
 mouseMove: function(e) {
  var coords = this.getMouseCoords(e);
  this.img.style.left = 
   (coords[0]+this.mouseOffset.x) + 'px';
  this.img.style.top = 
   (coords[1]+this.mouseOffset.y) + 'px';
 },
 addEvent: function(el, name, func, bool) {
  if (el == null || typeof name != 'string'
    || typeof func != 'function'
    || typeof bool != 'boolean')
   return;
  if (el.addEventListener)
   el.addEventListener(name, func, false);
  else if (el.attachEvent)
   el.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
  else
   el['on' + name] = func;
 },
 addEl: function(el) {
  var evts = ['over','out','move'],
   id = this.els.length;
  this.els.push(false);
  this.el = el;
  this.addEvent(el, 'mouseover', function(e) {
   this.mouseOver(e, id) }.bind(this), false);
  this.addEvent(el, 'mouseout', function(e) {
   this.mouseOut(e, id) }.bind(this), false);
  this.addEvent(el, 'mousemove', function(e) {
   this.mouseMove(e) }.bind(this), false);
  if (typeof el['style'] != 'undefined')
   el.style.cursor = 'none';
 },
 enable: function(src) {
  this.img.src = src;
  this.img.style.display = 'none';
  this.img.style.position = 'absolute';
  this.img.style.cursor = 'none';
  this.addEvent(this.img, 'mousemove', function(e) {
   this.mouseMove(e) }.bind(this), false);
  if (!this.addedImg)
   document.body.appendChild(this.img),
   this.addedImg = true;
 }
}

/*** INITIALIZE ***/
CursorJS.enable('http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/plastic-mini-icons-by-deleket/png/32x32/Cursor-01.png');
CursorJS.addEl(document.querySelector('.myElement1'));
CursorJS.addEl(document.querySelector('.myElement3'));
```

```css
.myElement1, .myElement2, .myElement3 {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement1">added</div>
<div class="myElement2">not added</div>
<div class="myElement3">added</div>
```

Hope that worked! Have a nice day :)